# iOS: Background image in UIImagePickerController is inconsistent with the rest of the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using the following code to set the navbar's background:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This results in a nice tiled background such as you see here:

[image: Good background]

However, when I open up a UIImagePickerController, the background is warped somehow and we end up with something like this:

[image: bad background]

Anyone have suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: is it happening on both the simulator and your physical device? Or just one of the two?

Answer (score 0):

Stretching instead of tiling: to Stop That
Create a class of type UINavigationBar

1. Create your custom UINavigationBar subclass.
2. Comment initwithFrameMethod
3. Add method DrawRect:

   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
     {
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebackground.jpeg"];
     [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
     }

4.in AppDelegate.m, AppliocationdidFinishLaunching
Write
 [self.navigationbar setValue:[[customBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];

Adding Image By this way will not stretch the image

Refer this Link:
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/09/custom-uinavigationbars-techniques/
http://designm.ag/tutorials/designing-a-custom-iphone-app-navigation-bar/

Hope this will help you.